# SQL Server 2017 Installation issues

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2017

When installing SQL Server 2017 on my computer/server I am receiving an installation error.

### Error Log

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068052377
  Start time:                    2018-08-13 13:34:16
  End time:                      2018-08-13 13:37:03
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for DQ:              Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for FullText:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for sql_inst_mpy:    Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for sql_inst_mr:     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for AdvancedAnalytics: Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for AS:              Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  DESKTOP-KJGHCSV
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (10.0.17134)
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
  SQL Server 2017                                                          Client Tools Connectivity                1033                                      14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017                                                          Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033                                      14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017                                                          Client Tools SDK                         1033                                      14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017                                                          Data Quality Client                      1033                 Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017                                                          Integration Services                     1033                 Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017                                                          Scale Out Master                         1033                 Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017                                                          Scale Out Worker                         1033                 Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017                                                          Master Data Services                     1033                 Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017                                                          Machine Learning Server (Standalone)                          Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017                                                          R                                                             Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017                                                          Python                                                        Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2017 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2017
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       14
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         C:\Users\HBopuri\Downloads\en_sql_server_2017_developer_x64_dvd_11296168\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Developer

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS14.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS14.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Config
  ASDATADIR:                     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS14.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS14.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            RADISE\HBopuri
  ASTELSVCACCT:                  NT Service\SSASTELEMETRY
  ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           Automatic
  ASTEMPDIR:                     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS14.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180813_133416\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad
  EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION, ADVANCEDANALYTICS, SQL_INST_MR, SQL_INST_MPY, FULLTEXT, DQ, AS
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:     true
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      true
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391
  ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:         <empty>
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ISTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISWORKERSVCCERT:               <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBPORTRANGE:                   <empty>
  PBSCALEOUT:                    false
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  SQL
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
  SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         true
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           RADISE\HBopuri
  SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY
  SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>
  SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            8
  SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
  SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180813_133416\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Data Quality Services
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          1639
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180813_133416\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=sql_engine_core_inst.msi%400x162A16FE%400x1639

  Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          1639
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180813_133416\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=sql_engine_core_inst.msi%400x162A16FE%400x1639

  Feature:                       Python
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          1639
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180813_133416\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=sql_engine_core_inst.msi%400x162A16FE%400x1639

  Feature:                       R
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          1639
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180813_133416\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=sql_engine_core_inst.msi%400x162A16FE%400x1639

  Feature:                       Machine Learning Services (In-Database)
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          1639
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180813_133416\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=sql_engine_core_inst.msi%400x162A16FE%400x1639

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          1639
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180813_133416\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=sql_engine_core_inst.msi%400x162A16FE%400x1639

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          1639
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180813_133416\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=sql_engine_core_inst.msi%400x162A16FE%400x1639

  Feature:                       Analysis Services
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Analysis Services
  Component error code:          1639
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180813_133416\sql_as_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=sql_as.msi%400x162A16FE%400x1639

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180813_133416\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

### Core Components Log File

*C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180813_133416\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log*

```
=== Verbose logging started: 08/13/2018  13:36:57  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\SQL2017\x64\ScenarioEngine.exe ===
MSI (c) (8C:28) [13:36:57:364]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (8C:28) [13:36:57:364]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (8C:28) [13:36:57:364]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\Users\HBopuri\Downloads\en_sql_server_2017_developer_x64_dvd_11296168\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (8C:28) [13:36:57:364]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (8C:28) [13:36:57:364]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (8C:28) [13:36:57:365]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (8C:28) [13:36:57:365]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (8C:28) [13:36:57:365]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (7C:E8) [13:36:57:367]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\Users\HBopuri\Downloads\en_sql_server_2017_developer_x64_dvd_11296168\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst.msi
MSI (s) (7C:E8) [13:36:57:367]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (7C:AC) [13:36:57:368]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (7C:AC) [13:36:57:368]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (7C:AC) [13:36:57:368]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\Users\HBopuri\Downloads\en_sql_server_2017_developer_x64_dvd_11296168\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (7C:AC) [13:36:57:368]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
MSI (s) (7C:AC) [13:36:57:368]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
MSI (s) (7C:AC) [13:36:57:368]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (7C:AC) [13:36:57:368]: Specified instance {DED314CA-0EFE-4593-9D66-EF75E5289A4C} via transform :InstID01.mst;:InstName01.mst is already installed. MSINEWINSTANCE requires a new instance that is not installed.
MSI (s) (7C:AC) [13:36:57:369]: MainEngineThread is returning 1639
MSI (s) (7C:E8) [13:36:57:369]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (7C:E8) [13:36:57:369]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (7C:E8) [13:36:57:369]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (7C:E8) [13:36:57:370]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (7C:E8) [13:36:57:370]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (7C:E8) [13:36:57:370]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (8C:28) [13:36:57:371]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (8C:28) [13:36:57:371]: MainEngineThread is returning 1639
=== Verbose logging stopped: 08/13/2018  13:36:57 ===
```

I have tried completely uninstalling SQL Server and then reinstalling, but I am still receiving an error message and the installation fails.

Comment: Running the installer as administrator might make it work.

Answer (score 4):

The reason it failed is because of below.

> MSI (s) (7C:AC) [13:36:57:368]: Specified instance {DED314CA-0EFE-4593-9D66-EF75E5289A4C} via transform :InstID01.mst;:InstName01.mst is already installed. MSINEWINSTANCE requires a new instance that is not installed.

This means in the windows installer registry there is remnants of previous installation which has left orphaned entries there. You have to manually remove it or use some tool.

[This Blog](http://sqlpost.blogspot.com/2009/06/orphan-msi-entries-during-sql-server.html) talks about similar issue and used MS tool to cleanup registry. The link in the blog is dead this is [Free windows installer cleanup utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.08.utilityspotlight.aspx) which you can use for cleanup.

**PS: Please backup the complete registry before you perform any cleanup**. I am not sure how this cleanup utility works so you have to do on your own risk

Comment: When I tried that command from that blog I got following error "Unexpected error: 1605 ()"

Comment: Did you missed the [This blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2005/07/01/using-msiinv-to-gather-information-about-what-is-installed-on-a-computer/) in the first link I shared. You need to download `msiinv.zip` file and follow instruction from the blog. Moreover the script is to check if there is orphaned msi there

Answer (score 0):

If you have any other server, Go to Services and stop the services that are running on the same port that is used by SQL server. I had the same problem, I stopped the MySQL services running and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

existe una herramienta proporcionada por Microsoft que ayuda a solucionar problemas que impiden instalar o desinstalar programas, sirve para Windows 10, 8.1, 8, 7

Click al siguiente enlace:
https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/solucionar-problemas-que-impiden-instalar-o-desinstalar-programas-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d

Translated:

There is a tool provided by Microsoft that helps to solve problems that prevent installing or uninstalling programs, it works for Windows 10, 8.1, 8, 7

Click on the following link: https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/solucionar-problemas-que-impiden-instalar-o-desinstalar-programas-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! This is an English language forum - so, in future, could you please provide translations in English?